# Find the location(Indices) of N elements in a huge numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a set of say, 5 elements,

```
[21,103,3,10,243]
```

and a huge Numpy array

```
[4,5,1,3,5,100,876,89,78......456,64,3,21,245]
```

with the 5 elements appearing repetitively in the bigger array.
I want to find all the Indices where the elements  of the small list appears in the larger array.
The small list will be less than `100` elements long and the large list will be about `10^7` elements long, and so, speed is a concern here. What is the most elegant and the fastest way to do it in python3.x ?

I have tried using `np.where()` but it works dead slow. Looking for a faster way.

Comment: Do you want to have the indices per element of the small list or an overall collection of indices at which any of the items is? Maybe you can provide a small example input and expected output?

Comment: @DavidWierichs I want the indices per element of the small list. For, e.g, say i have only one element in the small array A=[1], and the large array is B=[1,2,4,3,2,5,1,3,1,4,5]. I would expect the output to be [0, 6, 8] i.e the indices where 1 appears in the larger array.

Comment: Depending on your use case, you could achieve better than O(n) complexity by creating a lookup index, in case this is a task that is repeated often for varying small arrays. The lookup index could be as simple as a Python dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the 100 elements to be found in a `set`, a hash table.
Then loop through the elements of the huge array asking if the element is in the set.

```
S = set([21,103,3,10,243])
A = [4,5,1,3,5,100,876,89,78......456,64,3,21,245]
result = []
for i,x in enumerate(A):
  if x in S:
    result.append(i)
```

Comment: Let me try this and i will get back to you if it works or not. Just as a side note, is it supposed to be faster than np.where()?

Comment: @noobprogrammer I don't know. How exactly are you using `numpy.where`? What I wrote tries to take advantage of membership in a hash table taking constant time in amortized time. Then, the bottleneck should be traversing the huge array. So, theoretically, the growth of the number of steps in terms of the size `n` of the huge array would be O(n), which is the best that one can hope. Judging speed of a concrete run, however, is harder. The easiest way is to experiment. Give a try.

Comment: I just checked it out. Turns out its much faster than using np.where(). Thank you.

Comment: @noobprogrammer I suspect your problem was really on what condition you put inside the `numpy.where`, rather than the `numpy.where` itself.

Comment: No, actually i ran it correctly with np.where() but it took me a solid 20 minutes to go through it, whereas, the method you mentioned did it in less than asecond.

Answer (score 1):

To speed up things, you can optimize like this:

1. Sort the larger array
2. Perform binary search (on the larger array) for each number in the smaller array.

#### Time Complexity

Sorting using `numpy.sort(kind='heapsort')` will have time complexity `n*log(n)`.
Binary search will have complexity `log(n)` for each element in the smaller array. Assuming, there are `m` elements in the smaller array, the total search complexity will be `m*log(n)`.

Overall, this will provide you good optimization.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry i didn't mention it earlier, but sorting is not an option as the indices are linked to other lists and cannot be changed.

Comment: A workaround for this can be to create another list and store tuples `(value, index)` in it. It will help to backtrack the solution. You can then sort this array based on the first value of tuple and follow the above method. But, it will use a lot of memory.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Btw, i found a solution in the answer above. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

smaller_array = [21,103,3,10,243]
bigger_array = [4,5,1,3,5,100,876,89,78,456,64,3,21,243,243]
print(bigger_array)
print(smaller_array)
for val in smaller_array:
if val in bigger_array:
c = bigger_array.index(val)
while True:
print(f'{val} is found in bigger_array at index {bigger_array.index(val,c)}')
c = bigger_array.index(val,c)+1
if val not in bigger_array[c:]:
break

Answer (score 0):

```
smaller_array = [21,103,3,10,243]

bigger_array = [4,5,1,3,5,100,876,89,78,456,64,3,21,243,243]

print(bigger_array)

print(smaller_array)

for val in smaller_array:

    if val in bigger_array:

        c=0

        try:
            while True:
                c = bigger_array.index(val,c)
                print(f'{val} is found in bigger_array at index {c}')
                c+=1
        except:
            pass
```